# gteeing invalid literal for int() while excuting a python3 scrypt

Tags: python-3.x, linux, nic

i'm using a python script from the opencommunity for getting thi NIC card speed, which is working fine on the python2.7 but in python3.6 its not working .

**Below is the script:**

```
import subprocess
import netifaces
import socket
import re

hst_name = (socket.gethostname())

def get_Inf():
    global Current_inf
    Current_inf = netifaces.gateways()['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][1]
    return Current_inf

def get_bondSpeed():
    spd1 = open('/sys/class/net/{}/speed' .format(Current_inf)).read().strip()
    return spd1

def get_intSpeed():
    spd = subprocess.Popen(['/sbin/ethtool', get_Inf()], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    pat_match=re.search(".*Speed:\s+(\d+)+.*", int(spd))
    speed = pat_match.group(1)
    return speed

if get_intSpeed() == str(1000):
  print("Service Status:  System is running with 1Gbit Speed on the host",hst_name)
elif get_intSpeed() == str(10000):
  print("Service Status:  System is running with 10Gbit Speed on the host",hst_name)

elif get_bondSpeed() == str(10000):
  print("Service Status:  System is running with 10Gbit Speed on the host",hst_name, "with bond setup!")

elif get_bondSpeed() == str(1000):
  print("Service Status:  System is running with 1Gbit Speed on the host",hst_name, "with bond setup!")

elif get_bondSpeed() == str(2000):
  print("Service Status:  System is running with 2Gbit Speed on the host",hst_name, "with bond setup!")

else:
  print("Service Status:  System is not running with Gig Speed, Please check manually on the host",hst_name)
get_Inf()
```

**Error while trying:**

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "./getSpeedInfo.py", line 36, in <module>
    if get_intSpeed() == str(1000):
  File "./getSpeedInfo.py", line 32, in get_intSpeed
    pat_match=re.search(".*Speed:\s+(\d+)+.*", int(spd))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'Settings for ens192:\n\tSupported ports: [ TP ]\n\tSupported link modes:   1000baseT/Full \n\t                        10000baseT/Full \n\tSupported pause frame use: No\n\tSupports auto-negotiation:
```

### Command output: this is the output from the command line

```
# ethtool ens192
Settings for ens192:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full
                                10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  Not reported
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        MDI-X: Unknown
        Supports Wake-on: uag
        Wake-on: d
        Link detected: yes
```

any help on this will be much appreciated

Comment: You are right i think.

Comment: @Philippe, yes if you can put your answer here surely you can get that. `1000baseT/Full` <- this is where its failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get ValueError because you are trying to convert a binary string (containing non-numeric) to int.

To fix it, try :

```
    pat_match=re.search(b".*Speed:\s+(\d+).*", spd)
    speed = pat_match.group(1).decode()
```

As the result of `subprocess.Popen` is binary string, so I added `b` in `b".*Speed:\s+(\d+).*"` and removed `int()` around `spd`.

Now the result of `pat_match.group(1)` is again binary string, `.decode()` is needed.

Comment: But how to fix that in the code?

Comment: @krock1516 Answer updated.

Comment: @ Philippe, thnx a lot, i have accepted as an answer however, bounty has its predefined time which say can only prove in next 2 hours, will do that then.  Can you little explain the change you done.